# Using sysdate in hibernate insert/update query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, orm

I have an object of type javax.persistence.Query in which there is a native PL/SQL query (for Oracle) like:

```
BEGIN
  merge into account t 
  using dual 
  ON (t.account_id = '1') 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    update  set name=?, updated_date=? where account_id=? 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert  (name, account_id, created_date) values (?, ?, ?);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

I also have a list of positional parameters for the above which look like:
    'some-name', '01/01/2013 00:00:00', '1'

Problem is that I want to replace the parameter for updated_date/created_date with sysdate so that my final go-to-DB query looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  merge into account t 
  using dual 
  ON (t.account_id = '1') 
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    update  set name=?, updated_date=sysdate where account_id=? 
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    insert  (name, account_id, created_date) values (?, sysdate, ?);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

But if I specify one of the positional parameters as 'sysdate', it is taken literally by Hibernate as a string and I get an error.
How do I tell Hibernate that I want to specify the keyword sysdate and not the string 'sysdate' ?

For some reason, it is not possible for us to use triggers or JVM date (details omitted for simplicity)

// Update after Martin's response

Hi Martin, Thanks for your answer.

I am seeing the code as advised by you but cannot make anything out of it.
Most likely there is some small piece that I am missing and would be great if you can help me to it.
I will just post the relevant code sections to show what I am seeing.

```
public class PostgresUUIDType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<UUID> 
{
    public static final PostgresUUIDType INSTANCE = new PostgresUUIDType();

    public PostgresUUIDType() {
        super( PostgresUUIDSqlTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, UUIDTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE );
    }
}


// which calls
public AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor, JavaTypeDescriptor<T> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        super( sqlTypeDescriptor, javaTypeDescriptor );
}


// which calls
public AbstractStandardBasicType(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor, JavaTypeDescriptor<T> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        this.sqlTypeDescriptor = sqlTypeDescriptor;
        this.javaTypeDescriptor = javaTypeDescriptor;
}


// And the BasicTypeRegistry looks like this:

class BasicTypeRegistry {

    public BasicTypeRegistry() {
        register( BooleanType.INSTANCE );
        register( NumericBooleanType.INSTANCE );
        register( TrueFalseType.INSTANCE );
        ...
    }


    void register(BasicType type) {
        for ( String key : type.getRegistrationKeys() ) {
            final Type old = registry.put( key, type );
        }
    }

}
```

Can you please help me connect the dates here ?
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: create another similar query, where sysdate is hard-coded, and call this query.

Answer (score 0):

To control the way hibernate understands a given parameter object it uses the BasicTypeRegistry. Take a look at this class: `org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType` it adds support for a special postgres type. You can even find more examples of basic types by taking a look at the constructor of `org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry`. It contains all the BasicTypes mapped by hibernate.

By creating your own BasicType and use a custom object representation of your keyword like Sysdate or even new OracleKeyword("sysdate") as a parameter for your query, Hibernate will use your BasicType implementation to map it to SQL. So now your BasicType implementation gives you total control how the final outcome (SQL) will look like.

Note that you need to add your basic type to the type resolver before creating the session factory `configuration.getTypeResolver().registerTypeOverride(...)`.

**Update**:

The idea is that you with the BasicType you can specify the actual SQL text that is written out directly. Its a bit of a hack since the value actually is something you write.

The key part is:

```
 public static class PostgresUUIDSqlTypeDescriptor implements SqlTypeDescriptor {
    public static final PostgresUUIDSqlTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new PostgresUUIDSqlTypeDescriptor();

    public int getSqlType() {
        // ugh
        return Types.OTHER;
    }
```

See the Types.OTHER. And within the getBinder method you become a chance to control the SQL directly. Sadly I can only remember that this is the way we went some years ago. So I try to recapitulate a bit - beware that to find this helpful you might add some additional research:

```
public <X> ValueBinder<X> getBinder(final JavaTypeDescriptor<X> javaTypeDescriptor) {
        return new BasicBinder<X>( javaTypeDescriptor, this ) {
            @Override
            protected void doBind(PreparedStatement st, X value, int index, WrapperOptions options) throws SQLException {
                st.setObject( index, javaTypeDescriptor.unwrap( value, UUID.class, options ), getSqlType() );
            }
        };
    }
```

This is the getBinder method. Here you see the doBind method of the basic binder the type provides. Within the doBind method you get the prepared statement, X is the value you map and int is the index your parameter value is expected to be apply to.

At this point you have control what and how to set the parameter too. And if I am correct you can reference keywords or functions of your underlying database as parameter values. So using this way you can now fall back to jdbc and test if you can specify sysdate to be a parameter value. So if you get this working in JDBC you can get it working with hibernate using a basic type.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have put my response in the question.
Can you please give me some more details about this?

Answer (score 0):

Here I found an even better way to do what you want to do. Using an EnhancedUserType you can control the actual SQL written to represent the object directly. Check out the objectToSQLString method.

Just return "sysdate" within this method and your problem should be solved. Writing a simple user type for this is also very simple. Check out some of the example user types of hibernate and search google for additional examples.

Here is the original code of the EnhancedUserType interface including some comments.

```
package org.hibernate.usertype;

 public interface EnhancedUserType extends UserType {
/**
 * Return an SQL literal representation of the value
 */
public String objectToSQLString(Object value);

/**
 * Return a string representation of this value, as it
 * should appear in an XML document
 */
public String toXMLString(Object value);
/**
 * Parse a string representation of this value, as it
 * appears in an XML document
 */
public Object fromXMLString(String xmlValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used @ColumnTransformer(write="") and it works very well besides being really simple to use.

It helps you cherry pick a write-expression for a column which is inserted into the final query everytime an insert or update query is executed by hibernate.

Reference link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-column-read-and-write